# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'draw_line' in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

so I am trying to create the koch snowflake using python, at the moment I am debugging my code but I get keep getting this error when I try to draw a line. At the moment I am only trying to draw the first iteration of the koch snowflake, so there is no recursion yet.

This is the function for drawing a line on the canvas.

```
def draw_line(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
    self.canv.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=self.colour)
```

This is for rotating the points using the rotation matrix by an angle of 60

```
def rotate_points(self, xa, ya, xb, yb, angle):
    sin, cos = math.sin(angle), 0.5
    x_c = cos*(xb-xa)-sin*(yb-ya) + xa
    y_c = sin*(xb-xa)+cos*(yb-ya) + ya
    return x_c, y_c
```

This is for calculating the coordinates of the apex of the equilateral triangle of the koch triangle.

```
def trisection(self, x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1):
    # calculating one third and 2 thirds of the line segment (x_a, y_a) and (x_b, y_b)
    x_a = (2*x_0)/3 + x_1/3
    y_a = (2*y_0)/3 + y_1/3
    x_b = x_0/3 + (2*x_1)/3
    y_b = y_0/3 + (2*y_1)/3
    return x_a, y_a, x_b, y_b
```

This is for drawing the first iteration of the koch snowflake/curve.

```
def draw_base(self):
    xa, ya, xb, yb = self.trisection(0, self.canv_length/2, 500, self.canv_length/2)
    c1, c2 = (xa, ya), (xb, yb)
    xc, yc = self.rotate_points(xa, ya, xb, yb, -60)
    self.canv.draw_line(x0, y0, xa, ya)
```

The last line is where the error displays. But I don't know why. First three functions work perfectly, I have tested them as well, but last function is not.

Comment: The error is telling you that `self.canv` is an integer and not a canvas.

Comment: `self.canv` is an integer.  Integers do not have a `draw_line()` method.  Apparently you were expecting `self.canv` to be something else...

Comment: I imagine you want `self.draw_line()` instead of `self.canv.draw_line()`

Comment: Do remember, please, that `math.sin` accepts angles in radians, not degrees,

Comment: That means that `self.canv` is an `int`. If you think it should be something else, look to all of the places in your code where you assign something to it. That's where the bug will be.